# ¿Por que solo carga una vez los emoticonos en js jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando la librería de emoticonos DisMojiPicker
Tengo dentro de un modal un div para cargarlos y lo mismo en otro
`<div class="emojis"></div>`

Para que funcione tengo las librerías importadas y:

```
        $(".emojis").disMojiPicker();
        twemoji.parse(document.body);
        $(".emojis").picker(
            emoji => $('#mensaje-res').val($('#mensaje-res').val() + emoji)
        );
    });
```

pero cuando entro sucede lo siguiente,
en un sitio donde esta el div muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el otro sitio con el otro div muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por que en un div los carga y en otro no?

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Gracias por responder @PabloLozano si, pero son los que ya me aparecian de antes:  [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #titulo-res: (More info: <input name="titulo-res" type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo-res" required> Pero no es nada, es que tengo duplicado el modal y tiene el mismo id

Comment: Creo que es un defecto de la librería, inyecta en el DOM elementos con un ID determinado y entonces, al intentar usarlo dos veces, no encuentra nunca el segundo

Comment: Puedes ver el código fuente aquí: https://github.com/Je7z/disMojiPicker/blob/master/js/DisMojiPicker.js

Comment: Si, tiene pinta que es un error, pero ahora mismo viendo el código no veo posible solución... gracias igualmente @PabloLozano

Comment: Puedes modificar el código de la librería, para que no use la misma ID siempre. Y hacer un PullRequest a github :)

Comment: @RubenAmezcua, cuando mencionas _"es que tengo duplicado el modal y tiene el mismo id"_, tú mismo deberías haber notado que esa es la causa del error, porque el mensaje es precisamente por ese ID duplicado: _[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id **#titulo-res**_. Edita la pregunta para explicar porqué tienes dos elementos con mismo ID y, seguramente, vamos a poder sugerir cómo evitarlo.

Comment: Gracias pero ya lo he solucionado @Triby, he duplicado las funciones con nombres diferentes y llamo a las 2